# Group Layers in Flex Viewer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-viewer

Is there any way to add Layer groups in ArcGIS Flex Viewer layer widget?
For example I have about 30 layers that are all other companies fiber networks. I would love for the user to be able to turn those all on or off at once. It is a burden for the end user to have to turn them all on and off one by one. The image below shows only some of the layers that need to be turned on individually, as you can see it would be cumbersome.

[image: Layer List Current]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a Way around it. Just Published another service with those layers only, and made it "type=dynamic" in the config file when adding that service.  That way I am able to turn off and on the independent ones As seen in the screenshot. Thanks!

[image: Fixed Layer List]